# How to layout buttons and text on top of background ImageView

Tags: android

I want to create a linear layout with buttons and text but I need a background ImageView so I can change the image in teh background. The controls on top would be semi transparent so the image underneath shows through. How to do using Android SDK 2.3 or above

Thanks

Comment: background ImageView, can you eleborate it more?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lila_background"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/img_background"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
>
```

And when you need the change i think it's something like..

```
 ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lila_background)).setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.image_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi just need to add android:background="@drawable/addon" to ur layout xml